# Raspberry pi first boot, IP address

Tags: raspbian, ssh, boot-issues, static-ip, putty

I am using Raspberry PI B+ and I have installed Raspbian Wheezy OS using win32disk imager( I am using windows 7 PC). Now to use SSH, I am using Putty and Xming and putty requires IP address to move ahead.
Seeing some videos I edited the cmdline.txt file of the OS. Added ip=169.254.0.2( added range of IP according to me ethernet address also), used nmap to find IP address, but still no response.
The LAN in the control panel is showing it connected, even checked someone else's installed and booted OS on my pi it was working so it is some software issue only.
Please help!!!

Comment: This is not substantially different from your last question, beyond the fact that now there is *no question* at all.  This isn't a discussion forum, please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour).  You need to be precise and ask about things that might possibly have a definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't edit the cmdline. Don't use the ip address in putty but the raspberry's hostname, "raspberrypi".